# Getting uptime on a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I've got this code where I'm trying to make a kernel module print the [uptime](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uptime) of the system, exactly on the **simple_init**.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */

int simple_init(void)
{
    struct sysinfo info;
    sysinfo(&info);
    printk("This pc has been on for %ld seconds\n", info.uptime);;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I would do if this wasn't a kernel module, I found that there's a similar linux library for sysinfo which is **linux/sysinfo**, but even when I use that one, it only has a Struct sysinfo and not a function I can call sysinfo(), and when I try to do so I get

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘sysinfo’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     sysinfo(&info);
```

Does anyone knows any other effective approach?

Thanks

Comment: @jxh, I'm relatively new to C, I checked the link, but didn't saw anything relevant to my purpose, can I get a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the information you seek is provided by the kernel pseudofile `/proc/uptime`, we can look at [fs/proc/uptime.c:uptime_proc_show()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/uptime.c) in the kernel sources to see how the information is gathered.

Currently, the relevant code is

```
#include <linux/ktime.h>

    struct timespec  uptime;
    get_monotonic_boottime(&uptime);
```

where `uptime.tv_sec` is the number of seconds, and `uptime.tv_nsec` nanoseconds (0 to 999,999,999 inclusive).

However, since the kernel is moving to 64-bit time, you'd better use

```
#include <linux/ktime.h>

    s64  uptime_ms;
    uptime_ms = ktime_to_ms(ktime_get_boottime());
```

to get the uptime in milliseconds. If you only need the full seconds, use

```
#include <linux/ktime.h>

    s64  uptime;
    uptime = ktime_divns(ktime_get_coarse_boottime(), NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

("coarse" meaning only the full seconds part are read.)

Comment: I was asking for up time, and by that I mean the amount of time the computer has been active, Nothing about memory on my question.

Comment: @DiegoContreras: Right; now fixed to actually answer your question.  (I just derped there for a moment; sorry for the confusion!)